# fetch two values in python from .txt file

Tags: python

I have a .txt file containing some values. I need to fetch two values at a time using python and perform some operations on it and then fetch the next two values.

I want to write a python script where I can fetch two values at a time. I am new to python.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the format of the file? For e.g. is there a single line with many values, multiple lines with 2 values per line, multiple lines with a single value per line, etc.

Comment: Please provide more information in what you tried so far and how many entries the txt file has and whether you need the values afterwards or just for a single computation.

Comment: .txt file has one value(float  number) per line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# Read the file first and split lines in a list
with open('temp.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()

# Loop through lines, two at a time
for i in range(0, len(lines), 2):   # Notice the last argument '2', it makes the loop step 2 at a time
    val1 = lines[i]
    val2 = lines[i+1]
    # Perform calculation on val1 and val2
```

Hope this helps.